# Pass operation scopes to API gateway authorizer or integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

The AWS API gateway's ability to deploy APIs based on an OpenAPI specification is nice, with support for lambda authorizers validating a request header etc. However, I am curious as to if/why it doesn't support passing the security context of the OpenAPI operation to the authorizer and/or the lambda integration?

For example, consider the [pet store example API](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/blob/master/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml) used everywhere. Let's look at one of the operations:

```
/pet:
    post:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Add a new pet to the store
      description: Add a new pet to the store
      operationId: addPet
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        '405':
          description: Invalid input
      security:
        - petstore_auth:
            - 'write:pets'
            - 'read:pets'
```

If this API is implemented on API gateway with a JWT passed as the `Authorization` request header, a Lambda authorizer can be invoked to verify the JWT and grant invocation of the lambda function implementing the `addPet` operation. The authorizer may e.g. assign the decoded claims of the JWT to the `requestContext` passed to the integration lambda, including e.g. `sub`, `scopes` etc usually found in a JWT.

However, the fact that this *operation requires* `write:pets` and `read:pets` scope is ignored by the API gateway, and must be manually implemented by the integration lambda. In other words, every implemented operation must manually check that the claims verified by the authorizer fulfills the requirements of the operation.

Is it possible to somehow automate this by

1. Passing the [security object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md#security-requirement-object) for the operation (which may have been inherited by a common security object or defined specifically for that operation) to the authorizer so that it may not only verify the JWT itself but also whether it fulfills the requirements of the invoked operation
2. Passing the security object as part of the `requestContext` to the integration lambda, so that one piece of common code could verify the required scopes instead of each operation having to implement code that is in sync with the OpenAPI specification (e.g. `getPet` requires `read:pets`, `addPet` requires `read:pets` + `write:pets`, etc etc)

If not possible, I find it strange that AWS chose not to include the possibility of passing the entire OpenAPI operation object as part of the `requestContext`, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

Right now I'm considering having my integration lambda also include the OpenAPI specification itself to enable centralized scope validation, but it seems less than ideal to have to include the OpenAPI yaml/json file with my code and parse it in runtime when the API gateway has processed that same specification moments earlier as part of invoking the lambda, and it just seems like a waste not to include it in the passed event, e.g. something like this:

```
{
        "resource": "/pets/{petId}",
        "path": "/pets/somepet",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
            "Authorization": "Bearer ey...",
        },
        "requestContext": {
            "resourceId": "someapi",
            "authorizer": {
                "jwt": "{\"exp\":1668704400,\"scopes\":[\"read:pets\"],\"aud\":\"https://petstore.com\",\"iss\":\"https://auth.petstore.com\",\"sub\":\"someone\"}",
                "principalId": "someone",
                "integrationLatency": 11
            },
            "resourcePath": "/pets/{petId}",
            "operationName": "getPetById",
            "security": { <------------------------- THIS IS WHAT I WANT
                "petstore_auth": [
                    "read:pets"
                ]
            },
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "path": "/dev/pets/somepet",
            "accountId": "someaccount",
            "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "stage": "dev",
            "apiId": "someapi"
        },
        "body": null,
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    },
```

If this was available, the integration lambda could have a common piece of code that simply verified that the available scopes fulfill the required scopes by comparing the scopes in the claims from `requestContext.authorizer.jwt` with the *required* scopes for the particular operation in `requestContext.security`.

In fact, I think it would make sense if the entire OpenAPI [operation object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md#operationObject) was passed in the `requestContext`, instead of as today simply the `operationName`.

Is there any way to configure API gateway to include more data from the OpenAPI document in the `requestContext`?